# AngularJS - Displaying nested items from a REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am working on a portfolio project that is using a REST backend to serve JSON to an AngularJS frontend.  Below is an example of a JSON object that I am sending, formatted for readability.

```
    "fields": 
    {
        "description": "This is a test tree for JSON serialization",
        "name": "Test tree 1",
        "techniques": [1,2]
    },
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "dominion.tree"
```

I am at a novice level with Angular, so I am running into issues trying to display the techniques attached to this tree.

Currently, I have a directive called tree that will pull the JSON data and make it available for use and display.  Nested inside of that, I have an ng-repeat that goes over each technique id in the tree and calls a technique directive that takes the id as a parameter to pull that technique from the database.

tree.html

```
<trees>
    <div ng-repeat="pk in jsonstuff">
        {{pk.fields.name}}
        <div ng-repeat="technique in pk.fields.techniques">
            <technique idnum='{{technique}}'>
                {{techniqueJSON}}
            </technique>
        </div>
    </div>
</trees>
```

technique directive

```
.directive("technique", function(){
    return{
    scope: {id: '@idnum'},
    transclude: 'true',
    controller: function($scope, $http, $attrs) {

    techniqueJSON = {}
    urlstuff = 'http://localhost:8000/dominion/api/techniques/' + $scope.id
        $http.get(urlstuff).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        techniqueJSON = data
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
    },
    controllerAs: 'techniqueCtrl',
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'}
})
```

I don't want to use the techniqueJSON information inside of the template, because depending on where in the application this directive is, it can show a different subset of data.  My solution to that is to try and access the techniqueJSON object in a binding in the HTML inside of the directive tag.

That doesn't appear to be working, and I believe it is because of the isolate scope required for the {{technique}} binding to be evaluated properly instead of being set to undefined or passed in literally as /dominion/api/techniques/{{technique}}

From the top down, my questions are as follows:

- Is only referencing the primary key of the techniques in the tree the right decision from a REST API standpoint, or should I serialize the technique information along with the tree whenever a tree is requested?
- Is there a better way to call for this information from the Angular side, rather than using separate directives?  (i.e. calling a looped $http.get() for the technique inside of the tree's $http.get)
- Is there a better way to pass the ID numbers between the separate directives which means I could avoid having to use isolate scope?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/904r87k9/2/). Well, I use `user` as the model object in the demo.

Create a factory `UserFactory` and expose two functions `ids` and `user`. Any directives/controllers who want to fetch the user data can inject this factory and call the API.

I also corrected some errors from your code, such as `techniqueJSON = {}` should be `$scope.techniqueJSON = {}`.

> Note: I use [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) to simulate the `$http` call.

### Is only referencing the primary key ...

Yes. The display of every item should be controlled by the `technique` directive independently.

### Is there a better way to call for this information from the Angular side...

I would always suggest extracting the `data fetching` logic into a `service`/`factory`. This is easier to maintain. In addition, the data can be cached and reused across different controllers/directives.

Such kind of `factory` serves as the `model base` in front-end.

### Is there a better way to pass the ID numbers between the separate directives which means I could avoid having to use isolate scope?

It is fine to use isolate scope. The power of isolate scope is to make your directive independent. Because the isolate scope is not connected to other scopes through prototypical inheritance. It ensures that changes outside the directive only affect it through the binding. And vice versa for changes inside.

---

### Update

If you want to make the content of the directive more flexible, using `transclude:true` may be what you want. But `transclude: true` is designed to be with no relationship with isolate scope. **Angular creates a new scope for `transcluded` content. This scope is a sibling of the isolate scope.** So the transcluded content cannot access the values on isolate scope.

For example, suppose we have a directive `modal`. The directive cares only the popup, background, closing, position, etc. But inside the `modal`, we are able to put whatever content through `transclude: true`. This content should not have connection with the directive `modal`.

There is another way to achieve what you want: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rmgey7shU8t40uih2Ejk?p=preview).

Specify the `templateUrl` as a function, which returns the template name depending on some input parameter:

```
templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
    return 'template-' + attrs.tpl + '.html';
}
```

When you use it:

```
<technique idnum='{{id}}' tpl="a"></technique>
<technique idnum='{{id}}' tpl="b"></technique>
```

In this way, you can present the same `techniqueJSON` with different templates.

Comment: This is a pretty awesome answer, thank you.  In the example I used above, I wanted to use the inner HTML in <technique idnum='{{technique}}'> {{techniqueJSON}} </technique> to be able to access the data that was brought in by <technique>.  The reason for that is to have the ability to show different bits of the techniqueJSON data depending on where I'm at.  Would you suggest instead that I make separate directives each time that call the same factory data and vary their templates?

Comment: I was unaware you could use a function as the templateUrl, this is exactly what I needed.  Diving in headfirst into this stuff hasn't been easy, so your help is invaluable!  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. My pleasure.